# How do Europeans write a list of numbers with decimals?

Tags: localization, number-formatting

As I understand it, Europeans(*) write numbers with a comma for a decimal separator, so one-and-a-quarter is written as `1,25`

Europeans also use commas to separate lists, so how do you write a list of decimal numbers?  I, as an Englishman, would write one-and-a-quarter, one-and-a-half, one-and-three-quarters like this:

```
1.25, 1.5, 1.75
```

How do you do that in Europe?

(Why is this a programming question?  Because I'm writing a program that will ask European users for a list of numbers!)

<sub>* For the purposes of this question, there are no English-speaking countries in Europe. :-)</sub>

Comment: I suggest asking the list of numbers from the users in such a way that a comma is not used as separation symbol (e.g., tell the user to separate numbers by space only)

Comment: ";" is something you'll see often.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. The comma is used to group digits in larger numbers so 1000 is actually 1,000.

Comment: Some Europeans (specifically, Ukrainians) put a space after commas that are used as item separators, but they do not put a space after commas that are used as decimal part separators.

Comment: There are plenty of English-speaking countries in Europe: Ireland, Malta, the Netherlands, Norway, Sweden, Denmark, Cyprus, maybe others too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark How do you define "English-speaking countries in Europe"?

Comment: An English-speaking country is one in which English is very widely spoken. But don't take all SO comments too seriously :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This varies by culture, and within a culture. The CLDR data contains the [“list” elemen](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Number_Symbols)t that specifies the list separator character, and it is the semicolon for most cultures, see the [chart of number symbols](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/by_type/number.symbol.html) (element “list”). The definition is very implicit though, and there is variation inside locales. Some people regard 1,25, 1,5, 1,75 as acceptable, while others prefer 1,25; 1,5; 1,75. There are also people who seriously think that in a strongly mathematical or numeric context, one should deviate from the locale practices and use the Anglo-Saxon notation with decimal point, hence with comma as separator.

On the practical side, I think it would not be very wrong to use ”;” as number list separator when decimal comma is used, or even when decimal point is used. So you might even consider using ”;” in all locales.

But when it comes to *user input*, it’s trickier. In principle, you be liberal in what you accept, but since the comma can be meant to be a decimal comma, a thousands separator, or a list item separator, there is such a thing as being too liberal.

If possible, prompt for each number separately, avoiding the separator issue. If this is not possible, the crucial thing is to make it very, very clear to the use which separator is expected. I would go as far as saying that requiring for the semicolon ”;” is the most reliable thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

I'm European (french), and in almost all programs here we have to use semicolons `';'` as a separator, even if the numbers are only integers because the comma doesn't look like a separator for us. In mathematics, semicolons are the only right way here to separate a list of numbers.

The most common example is when we have to enter the page numbers we want to print on a PDF, all programs ask for a semicolon-separated list and I clearly found it intuitive. I think they would have changed it if it was uncomfortable for some.

Answer (score 3):

Why ask about Europeans in general ? I don't think there is one European way of doing so, and if it happens to be the case then it would be sheer luck. Europe is comprised of different cultures and each has its own rules.

You don't mention what platform you are using but you might be able to rely on your plaform to get this information. In the case of .NET, you can get this information through [Textinfo.ListSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.listseparator.aspx). For example this would give you the French one (result: a semicolon):

```
string listSeparator = new CultureInfo("fr-FR").TextInfo.ListSeparator;
```

Comment: +1. EUROPEAN is a very stupid term when this is a culture specific issue. Germany, UK, France and you already get into quite deep water with such details. Even german SPEAKING there is a difference for example between germany and switzerland for numbers - and switherland is in europe, geographically, though not in the EU. Dates are a lot worse ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one way to do it.  White space separating the numbers would works just the same, or you could use a semicolon (`';'`) to separate the numbers

Comment: A space may not be wise, as some locales (France I believe) use a space to separate groups of digits (thousands) in large numbers (where English users would use `,`s)... 
EN: 12,345.678
FR : 12 345,678 !