# Can i replace the period in decimal pad with a comma in Swift 2 iPhone app?

Tags: ios, localization, numbers

Or maybe add a comma on the number pad without creating a custom keyboard.
I tried changing NSLocale to to another country but that didn't work. I have a function that separates multiple numbers from textFiled to evaluate them separately separated by commas but the keyboards do not contain a comma and i would rather not use the numbers and punctuation keyboard for this. Any help is appreciated. Using Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear at all. The decimal pad shows either a `.` or a `,` depending on the user's locale. Why would you want to change this? Some locales expect numbers like `3.14` while other locales expect the numbers to be like `3,14`. You don't want to change that.

Comment: BTW - you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104071/how-do-europeans-write-a-list-of-numbers-with-decimals

Comment: “I have a function that separates multiple numbers from textFiled to evaluate them separately separated by commas”—he wants a number pad with a comma, so he can enter multiple numbers separated by commas. The standard number pad only has a period (at least in locales that use a period as the radix mark).

Comment: @robmayoff understood what i was saying  i don't know how i could have explained that any simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the keys on any of the built-in keyboards.

You can create your own keyboard view with the inputs you want (numbers, the comma, backspace) and set it as the `inputView` of your text field. The system will display your keyboard view instead of a standard keyboard when your text field becomes first responder.

Or you can just create, say, a toolbar with a comma button on it, and set the toolbar as your text field's `inputAccessoryView`, and let the text field use the standard decimal pad for numbers and backspace. The system will display your input accessory view above the standard keyboard when your text field becomes first responder.

Read [“Input Views and Input Accessory Views” in the *Text Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).

Comment: Thanks that's all i needed to know.